# Detect in Azure Notification Hub when an app has been uninstalled

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I need detect when an application has been uninstalled, in both Android and iOS. The purpose is update a table record in backend.

Seems it's not exists a "canonical way" to detect the uninstall in device side, but some people say it's possible handling the message error when you publish a push notification.

We use Azure Notification Hub, with class NotificationhubClient, but I can't see the value in response than alert the notification fail for uninstalled app. GCM must return a "Not registered" but I only receive "0 success" in result.
I can see too the registration of device as response of NotificationHubClient.GetAllRegistrations method. In the response of all registrations still appear the registration of device where I did uninstall app.

Really it's possible know only with Azure Notification Hub if app has been uninstalled? It's possible request to Firebase o Apple with registration IDs if they still be installed applications

Answer (score 1):

Doing some tests I can see the registrations of Azure disappear 1 or 2 hours after than the application it's uninstalled. This work in Android GCM. In iOS the registration still appear after this time.

Comment: For iOS/APNS I think you won't know until you try sending a notification to that device, and Apple reports back to the Notification Hub that the token is no longer valid.